Is my method of minimizing $f(x,y) = \frac xy + \frac{a-x}{b-y}$ on {$0<x<a, 0<y<b$} correct?
I have a function $f(x,y) = \frac xy + \frac{a-x}{b-y}$ and I was trying to find its min or max, but when I plugged it into Wolfram it said no global minima/maxima found. I assume this is because $x$ and $y$ can be any real numbers so I added the restrictions of $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$. Both $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. Within these boundaries $f(x,y)$ still has no maximum. If I use $x=\frac a2$ then $$f = \frac a2 \cdot \frac 1y + \frac{a-\frac a2}{b-y}$$ $$f = \frac a2 \cdot \frac 1y + \frac a2 \cdot \frac{1}{b-y}$$
$$f = \frac a2 \cdot \left( \frac 1y + \frac{1}{b-y}\right)$$ Then by using a right handed limit $$\lim_{y \to 0+} f\left(\frac a2, y\right) = \lim_{y \to 0+} \frac a2 \cdot \left( \frac 1y + \frac{1}{b-y}\right)$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0+} f\left(\frac a2, y\right) =\frac a2 \lim_{y \to 0+}  \left( \frac 1y + \frac{1}{b-y}\right)$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0+} f\left(\frac a2, y\right) =\frac a2 \left(\infty + \frac 1b \right)$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0+} f\left(\frac a2, y\right) =\frac a2 \left(\infty \right)$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0+} f\left(\frac a2, y\right) =\infty$$
Since $x=\frac a2$ and $y \to 0+$ are both within the domain, this shows there is no global maximum in the domain. So I wanted to find the minimum. I had the idea of assuming that $\frac xy$ has a fixed value $p$ ; the boundaries of the domain imply that $0<p<\infty$. Then $f(x,y)$ becomes
$$f(x,y) = \frac xy + \frac{a-x}{b-y}$$
$$f(x) = p + \frac{a-x}{b-\frac xp} = p + \frac{pa-px}{pb-x}$$
The derivative of this function is
$$f'(x) = \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} \left( p + \frac{pa-px}{pb-x}\right)$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}p + \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} \left(\frac{pa-px}{pb-x}\right)$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} \left(\frac{pa-px}{pb-x}\right)$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{(-p)(pb-x)-(pa-px)(-1)}{(pb-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{-p(pb-x)+(pa-px)}{(pb-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{-p(pb-x)+p(a-x)}{(pb-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{p[-(pb-x)+(a-x)]}{(pb-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{p[(x-pb)+(a-x)]}{(pb-x)^2}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{p(a-pb)}{(pb-x)^2}$$
I want the derivative to be nonzero and well-defined. To be well-defined, the denominator must be nonzero $$(pb-x)^2 \ne 0$$ $$pb-x \ne 0$$ $$x \ne pb$$ $$\frac xp \ne b$$
$$y \ne b$$ This condition is satsified as long as we stay in the domain. For the derivative to be nonzero, the numerator must be nonzero
$$p(a-pb) \ne 0$$
$$a-pb \ne 0$$ $$a \ne pb$$ $$\frac ab \ne p$$
If we select a value of $p$ such that $p \ne \frac ab$, then the derivative will be nonzero and well-defined, so it won't be able to change sign, making $f(x)$ monotonic. Then the minimum / lower bound will be found at either the highest or lowest value for $x$, which is $x \to 0+$ or $x \to a-$
$$\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0+} p + \frac{pa-px}{pb-x} = p + \frac{pa}{pb} = p + \frac ab$$
$$\lim_{x \to a-}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a-} p +\frac{pa-px}{pb-x} = p +\frac{pa-pa}{pb-a} = p$$
The second equation is justified because $p \ne \frac ab \implies pb - a \ne 0$. Since $\frac ab$ is positive, the smaller value is $p$.
On the section of the domain where $\frac xy = p$, the lower bound of $f(x,y)$ is $p$.
EDIT: I think my conclusion is wrong.
My new approach avoids calculus. Instead of trying to restrict $x$ and $y$ with $\frac xy = p$ we use the domain. The fact that $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$ is equivalent to $0< \frac xa < 1$ and $0 < \frac yb <1$. Now let $\frac xa = m$ and $\frac yb = n$. Then $x = ma$ and $y = nb$ so that
$$f(x,y) = \frac xy + \frac{a-x}{b-y}$$
$$f(x,y) = \frac {ma}{nb} + \frac{a-ma}{b-nb}$$
$$f(x,y) = \frac ab \cdot \frac mn + \frac ab \cdot \frac{1-m}{1-n}$$
$$f(x,y) = \frac ab \cdot \left(\frac mn + \frac{1-m}{1-n}\right)$$
Because $m,n \in (0,1)$ , both fractions inside the parentheses are positive. If $m>n$ the fraction on the left is greater than $1$ so the sum of the fractions is greater than $1$. If $m<n$ then
$$m<n$$ $$-m>-n$$ $$1-m>1-n$$ $$ \frac{1-m}{1-n}>1$$
so the sum of fractions is again greater than $1$. If $m=n$ then the expression becomes equal to $2$, again greater than $1$. This proves that
$$\left(\frac mn + \frac{1-m}{1-n}\right) > 1$$
$$\frac ab \cdot \left(\frac mn + \frac{1-m}{1-n}\right)>\frac ab$$
$$f(x,y)>\frac ab$$
My questions:
$\bullet$ We know $f(x,y)$ gets arbitrarily close to $p$ and $p$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$. Does that prove $f$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$? [Can we prove $f(x,y)$ gets arbitrarily close to $\frac ab$?]
$\bullet$ Is the logic I used to get to the conclusion correct? [No, but why?]
$\bullet$ Is there some clever trick that could prove the conclusion really quickly?

Since $ p = x/y$, you need to consider $ \frac{d}{dx} p $ which is non-zero. As such, the rest of the proof is wrong. $\quad$ (Note: you may want to assume that $y$ is independent of $x$? Or are you assuming that $y = px$? It's very confusing what you mean by $x/y$ has fixed value $p$, esp since they get to vary)

@CalvinLin I was assuming that $y = px$ with $p$ being a constant, focusing on only a part of the full domain.

Hint: The expression is linear in $x$, so the extrema happens at $   x \in \{ 0, a \}$. Thus, we need only concern ourselves with $f(0, y) = \frac{ a}{b-y}$ and $f(a, y) = \frac{ a}{y}$.
The infimum of $f(0,y)$ is $f(0,0) = \frac{a}{b}$, and the infimum of $f(a, y)$ is $f(a, b) = \frac{a}{b}$.
Hence, the infimum  of the expression is $ \frac{ a}{b}$.
